# Rails field on join entity in has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I may be going about this the wrong way but after reading various SO articles and the Rails docs on associations and scopes, I'm not much wiser.

I have a many-to-may relationship expressed like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_program_records
  has_many :programs, through: :user_program_records
end

class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_program_records
  has_many :users, through: :user_program_records
end

class UserProgramRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :program

  # has a field "role"
end
```

The idea is that there are many users in the system and many programs. Programs have many users in them and users may belong to multiple programs. However - within a given program, a user can only have one role.

What I'd really like to be able to write is:

```
Program.first.users.first.role
```

and have that return me the role (which is just a `String`).

What's the cleanest way to do this? Basically, once I've scoped a user to a given program, how do I cleanly access fields on the relevant join table?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. If you're asking for my opinion on your design, I would say it's a pretty standard Rails model association that will work well. I have identical associations set up in my app.

Comment: @Harfangk I see what you're saying. Let me update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking about it slightly wrong:

```
user.role
```

Would be very ambiguous as a user can have different roles in different programs. Instead you need to think of the join entity as a thing of its own.

The easiest way is to select the join model directly:

```
program = Program.includes(:user_program_records, :users).first
role = program.user_program_records
                .find_by(user: program.users.first)
                .role
```

You can use stuff like association extensions and helper methods to make this a bit sexier.

Comment: Interesting - thanks for the answer! I'll give this a try. My next challenge is to tackle integrating this with Devise, as users are logging in to a program.

Comment: With Devise you could do something like `role = current_user.user_program_records.find_by(program: @program).try(:role)`

Comment: hm, yeah, I'll have to play around with it. My plan is decorate some of the objects being passed around so that the role and program API is clean.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify it has a really nice API for doing resource scoped roles.

Comment: that looks *really* nice! Thanks for the tip.